# Linking multiple social accounts to Azur B2C local account through custom policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to link Azure B2C local account with multiple (Facebook, Google) social providers.

I've successfully setup the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/237fae7530197bf6e13bdc8ef2a9e6d9cf326b05/scenarios/source/aadb2c-ief-account-linkage/Readme.md).

But it always writes only one social provider to the local account. If I first link Facebook and then try to link also Google, Facebook userIdentities item is overwritten. And vice versa.

I've tried to replace the [Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile) with AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId but user object is not updated.

I think there might be an issue with the Protocol, which only overrides and does not append.

Only one social provider is included:

```
   "userIdentities": [
                {
                    "issuer": "google.com",
                    "issuerUserId": "MDExMDk2RTg3NTM0OTk3Mjk5OTI3"
                }
            ],
```

Here is a user journey part that updates the social account for a local user

```xml
        <!-- Demo: Updates the social account for a user, identified by the object
             identifier for the user, in the Azure AD identity store. 
             An error is raised if the user does not exist. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId-ThrowIfNotExists" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId-ThrowIfNotExists" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

```xml
And here is the corresponding Technical profile:

 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId-ThrowIfNotExists">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <!-- Demo: Persist the alternativeSecurityId claim -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
   </TechnicalProfile>
```

But the user object should contain both, Google and Facebook:

```
   "userIdentities": [
                {
                    "issuer": "google.com",
                    "issuerUserId": "MDExMDk2RTg3NTM0OTk3Mjk5OTI3"
                },
 {
                    "issuer": "facebook.com",
                    "issuerUserId": "KVExMDk2RTg3NTM0OTk3Mjk5OTI4"
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to and remove from the **userIdentities** property using [the social accounts claims transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/social-transformations).

Firstly, declare an **alternativeSecurityIds** claim:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="alternativeSecurityIds">
  <DisplayName>Alternative Security IDs</DisplayName>
  <DataType>alternativeSecurityIdCollection</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

Next, add the **alternativeSecurityIds** claim as an output claim to [the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/237fae7530197bf6e13bdc8ef2a9e6d9cf326b05/scenarios/source/aadb2c-ief-account-linkage/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L713), to get the existing user identities for a user:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
  <OutputClaims>
    ...
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityIds" />
  </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Next, declare an **AddAlternativeSecurityIdToAlternativeSecurityIds** claims transformation, to add a new alternative security ID item to an existing alternative security ID collection:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AddAlternativeSecurityIdToAlternativeSecurityIds" TransformationMethod="AddItemToAlternativeSecurityIdCollection">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" TransformationClaimType="item" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityIds" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityIds" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Next, add the **AddAlternativeSecurityIdToAlternativeSecurityIds** claims transformation as an output claims transformation to each of the social account claims providers, to add the new user identity (which is created by the **CreateAlternativeSecurityId** claims transformation) to the existing user identities (which was retrieved by the **AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId** technical profile) for the user:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>facebook.com</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Facebook</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Facebook-OAUTH">
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        ...
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AddAlternativeSecurityIdToAlternativeSecurityIds" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Finally, rather than the **alternativeSecurityId** claim, refer to the **alternativeSecurityIds** claim, as a persisted claim in [the **AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId-ThrowIfNotExists** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/237fae7530197bf6e13bdc8ef2a9e6d9cf326b05/scenarios/source/aadb2c-ief-account-linkage/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L106), to update the existing user identities for the user:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId-ThrowIfNotExists">
  <PersistedClaims>
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityIds" />
  </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: thank you! So basically we are creating a collection DataType and adding securityIds to it.